# How to made a multi-lang webpage with JSON and vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to made way to translate a webpage using JSON files and vanilla JS functions.

I have these 2 files:

*index.htm*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- blah blah blah -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> <var>GLOBAL.CONTENT.SAMPLE_TEXT</var> </h1>
        <h2> <var>OTHER.TEST.TEST</var> </h2>
        <p>
            <i> <var>GLOBAL.CONTENT.LOADING</var> </i>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

*en.json*

```
{
    "global": {
        "content": {
            "loading": "Loading...",
            "sample_text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
        }
    },
    "other": {
        "test": {
            "test": "THIS IS A TEST"
        }
}
```

I already know how to parse the JSON to a `new Object` variable and how to access to every variable.
But what I don't know is how to made every `<var></var>` to replace its actual content with its corresponding path, example:

```
<h1> <var>GLOBAL.CONTENT.LOADING</var> </h1>
     _________________________________
                     |
                     V
            <h1> Loading... </h1>
```

And so on... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using javascript `new Function` method

```js
//Parsed data
var json= {
    "global": {
        "content": {
            "loading": "Loading...",
            "sample_text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
        }
    },
    "other": {
        "test": {
            "test": "THIS IS A TEST"
        }
    }
};

//Insert the data
var varTags=document.getElementsByTagName("var");
for(var i =0;i<varTags.length;i++){
try{
  varTags[i].textContent=(
     new Function('return this.'+varTags[i].textContent.toLowerCase()+';')).call(json);
}catch(e){
   varTags[i].textContent="";
   console.log("Error in <var/> Tag: "+e.message);
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- blah blah blah -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> <var>GLOBAL.CONTENT.SAMPLE_TEXT</var> </h1>
        <h2> <var>OTHER.TEST.TEST</var> </h2>
        <p>
            <i> <var>GLOBAL.CONTENT.LOADING</var> </i>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant! It worked like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: @Davdriver please check my solution too, there's some error management and a possibility to use a placeholder if a translation is missing!

Comment: @b00t You are rigth i forget the error management at all,  I upvote you for the hint.

Comment: Sorry if I put a comment on this 4yr old post, but why are you using a Function object? Isn't it risky? Wouldn't it be better to just access to the textContent of the element directly?

Answer (score 2):

Add this in a `script` tag right before your `body` closes:

```js
// Object parsed from JSON data.
var translations = {
    "global": {
        "content": {
            "loading": "Loading...",
            "sample_text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
        }
    },
    "other": {
        "test": {
            "test": "THIS IS A TEST"
        }
    }
};

// Loop through each var element.
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('var'), function (translate) {
    // Parse the translation path.
    var path = translate
        .textContent
        .trim()
        .toLowerCase()
        .split('.');
    try {
        // Assumed that every translation is three levels deep, else print empty string.
        translate.textContent = path.length === 3 ? translations[path[0]][path[1]][path[2]] : '';
    } catch (e) {
        // Log errors to console if any, and use empty string instead of translation.
        console.error(e);
        translate.textContent = '';
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- blah blah blah -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> <var>GLOBAL.CONTENT.SAMPLE_TEXT</var> </h1>
        <h2> <var>OTHER.TEST.TEST</var> </h2>
        <p>
            <i> <var>GLOBAL.CONTENT.LOADING</var> </i>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's also a good code, but has a problem: The webpage will have a JSON file as input, which will have more or less "levels", while your code only seems to handle 3 levels (json.a.b.c, but neither json.a.b nor json.a.b.c.d).
Thus the choosen solution is the other one, which also do handle that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`document.getElementsByTagName('var')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) to retrieve all tags `var`. And use either [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) (if your templates only contais plain text) or [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) (if your templates contains HTML) to read out and modify the inner content.

```
var allVars = document.getElementsByTagName('var');
for(var i = 0; i < allVars.length; i++) {
    var thisVar = allVars[i];

    alert(thisVar.innerText);

    thisVar.innerText = 'Hi there';
}
```

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petervanderwal/4p3ubx3e/)

Comment: I want to know how to replace the content of each one with its corresponding in the `Object`. See the example.